How to connect SQL Server using domain authencation in laravel?
In Navicat I can connect to SQL Server using domain authentication.


But it cannot be connected in Laravel. Below is my connection config.
[
    "driver" => "sqlsrv",
    "url" => "ad.demo.com",
    "host" => "10.xx.xx.xx",
    "port" => "1550",
    "database" => "Database",
    "username" => "user1",
    "password" => "****",
    "charset" => "utf8",
    "prefix" => "",
    "prefix_indexes" => true,
]

Error message:

Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'user1'. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from [USERS])'


The client computer and the target SQL Server have to be in the same Active Directory domain (or trusted domains) for domain authentication to work. Except for the exceptions (such as the weird JDBC driver) you do not specify a username and password when using domain authentication, the client process just needs to be executing in the context of the correct user account.

For security reasons SQL Servers will never tell you why authentication fails, just that it does fail. If you have access to the target SQL Server instance's ERRORLOG you can check there for the Error 18456 Login Failure messages, take note of the State number that they report, and compare it against the list of State numbers at MSSQLSERVER_18456 to determine the cause of the login failure.

another point to note, you are missing the domain on "username" => "user1" i would expect a "username" => "domain\user1",
if you have just the user name without the domain, SQL will assume you are using SQL login instead of domain login. also change DB_HOST=localhost to DB_HOST=domain/sql server instance if not default instance  on  your env

thank you very much for your comment,Despite attempting various methods, the database connection remains unsuccessful. It is possible that the pdo_sqlsrv extension does not support this type of connection.
